# Check coincidence between a string and a vector of words in R

Tags: r

I am working on `R` with strings. My dataframe `DF` has next structure:

```
DF <- data.frame(v1=c(1,2,3),v2=c("Oranges are fruits","Hit music","Ferrari is red"),stringsAsFactors = F)

  v1                 v2
1  1 Oranges are fruits
2  2          Hit music
3  3     Ferrari is red
```

And I have a vector `d` which contains:

```
d <- c("fruits","red")
```

I am looking for a way to test if all strings in `v2` have coincidence with `d`. In this way, I have tried next code:

```
DF$v3 <- grepl(d,DF$v2)
```

But I get this result:

```
  v1                 v2    v3
1  1 Oranges are fruits  TRUE
2  2          Hit music FALSE
3  3     Ferrari is red FALSE
```

Which is not correct because string in third row of `v2` has word `red` that is contained in `d`. Is it any way to obtain an output like this:

```
  v1                 v2    v3
1  1 Oranges are fruits  TRUE
2  2          Hit music FALSE
3  3     Ferrari is red  TRUE
```

My original dataset is larger and `DF` is a sample of it. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `?grepl`, about the `pattern` argument:

> If a character vector of length 2 or more is supplied, the first element is used

so supplying the length 2 `d` will only search for `fruits`.

To see if any of the strings in `d` match, you can either use an approach with `any` and iteration, or instead collapse `d` with the `|` symbol to use as the pattern as below. Note that a sentence like "He was barred" will match for "red" in this example.

```r
DF <- data.frame(v1 = c(1, 2, 3), v2 = c("Oranges are fruits", "Hit music", "Ferrari is red"), stringsAsFactors = F)
d <- c("fruits", "red")

DF$v3 <- grepl(paste0(d, collapse = "|"), DF$v2)
DF
#>   v1                 v2    v3
#> 1  1 Oranges are fruits  TRUE
#> 2  2          Hit music FALSE
#> 3  3     Ferrari is red  TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use `apply` twice together with `grepl`. It is basically doing a double for loop. For each element in v2, the grepl is applied to each element of d.

```
DF$v3 <- sapply(DF$v2, FUN = function(s) any(sapply(d, FUN = grepl, s)))
DF
```